# Are ping results dropping when SCP'ing normal?

Tags: nginx, scp, response-time

Whilst scp'ing a file to a server, the ping responses of the server drops to be 6 times slow at ~640ms. Is this... normal? I'm using nginx, is this an indicator that it needs fine tuning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your pings are competing for bandwidth with your file transfer. So of course they will take longer. This most likely indicates that you've maxed out your home network's bandwidth.

Comment: heh, it's always the simple, most obvious solution that is the hardest to see!